# Read the data from a text file and reshape the data in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

I need to convert the following text file into csv format using Python pandas.
I have a dataset in the following format. It is a text file and doesn't have header.

[image: Input text file]

And I need it in a format like this:

```
SourceFile  RowNo ColNo Value
InputFile.txt   1   1   H1000
InputFile.txt   1   2   Sample_ID
InputFile.txt   1   3   MGA_E
InputFile.txt   1   4   MGA_N
InputFile.txt   2   1   H1001
InputFile.txt   2   2   Method
InputFile.txt   2   6   AR101
InputFile.txt   3   1   H1002
InputFile.txt   3   2   Units
InputFile.txt   3   3   metres
InputFile.txt   3   4   metres
InputFile.txt   4   1   H1003
InputFile.txt   4   2   LLD
InputFile.txt   4   6   0.01
InputFile.txt   4   7   5
InputFile.txt   5   1   D
InputFile.txt   5   2   DAL011
InputFile.txt   5   3   446500
InputFile.txt   5   4   6644000
InputFile.txt   5   5   L
InputFile.txt   5   6   9.13
InputFile.txt   6   1   D
InputFile.txt   6   2   DAL020
InputFile.txt   6   3   462800
InputFile.txt   6   4   6653400
InputFile.txt   6   5   L
InputFile.txt   6   6   8.6
InputFile.txt   7   1   EOF
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
if 'txt' in str(path_txt):
        all_dfs = pd.read_csv(str(path_txt), dtype=str, sep='\t', header=None)  # Reading file
       
else:
        print ('Unknow file', str(path_txt))
for (i, c) in enumerate(all_dfs.columns):
        ds = ds.append(pd.DataFrame({
            'SourceFile': path_txt.name,
            'RowNo': range(1, len(all_dfs) + 1),
            'ColNo': i + 1,
            'Value': all_dfs[[str(c)]].values[:, 0],
            }))                       
 ds['Value'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
 ds.dropna(subset=['Value'], inplace=True)
 ds.to_csv('Data.csv', index=False)
```

1. SourceFile(name of the  txt file)
2. RowNumber(which row, Value field is coming)
3. ColumnNumber(which column, value field is coming)
4. Value(actual data)

**Error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['0'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"**

Comment: Please 1. send the full text file _as text_ in the question (not image or table), and 2. show your full expected output dataframe based on the text file.

Comment: @user172425583 I made changes both in the input & output table.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my answer below and let me know if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will do exactly what you want, in a simpler (and faster) way:

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read().strip()

lines = [[('InputFile.txt', line_no + 1, col_no + 1, cell) for col_no, cell in enumerate(re.split('\t', l.strip())) if cell != ''] for line_no, l in enumerate(re.split(r'[\r\n]+', text))]
l = []
for line in lines:
    l.extend(line)
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['SourceFile', 'RowNo', 'ColNo', 'Value'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       SourceFile  RowNo  ColNo      Value
0   InputFile.txt      1      1      H1000
1   InputFile.txt      1      2  Sample_Id
2   InputFile.txt      1      3      MGA_E
3   InputFile.txt      1      4      MGA_N
4   InputFile.txt      2      1      H1001
5   InputFile.txt      2      2     Method
6   InputFile.txt      2      6      AR101
7   InputFile.txt      3      1      H1002
8   InputFile.txt      3      2      Units
9   InputFile.txt      3      3     metres
10  InputFile.txt      3      4     metres
11  InputFile.txt      4      1      H1003
12  InputFile.txt      4      2        LLD
13  InputFile.txt      4      6       0.01
14  InputFile.txt      4      7          5
15  InputFile.txt      5      1          D
16  InputFile.txt      5      2     DAL011
17  InputFile.txt      5      3     446500
18  InputFile.txt      5      4    6644000
19  InputFile.txt      5      5          L
20  InputFile.txt      5      6       9.13
21  InputFile.txt      6      1          D
22  InputFile.txt      6      2     DAL020
23  InputFile.txt      6      3     462800
24  InputFile.txt      6      4    6653400
25  InputFile.txt      6      5          L
26  InputFile.txt      6      6        8.6
27  InputFile.txt      7      1        EOF
```

I verified that it produces your expected output dataframe perfectly.